# Precedence: Logical or vs. Ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, operator-precedence, logical-or

Consider the following:
***(EDIT: I've amended the function slightly to remove the use or braces with the ternary operator)***

```js
function someFunction(start,end,step){
  var start = start || 1,
      end = end || 100,
      boolEndBigger = (start < end);   // define Boolean here
      step = step || boolEndBigger ? 1:-1;
  console.log(step); 
}

someFunction()
// step isn't defined so expect (1<10) ? 1:-1  to evaluate to 1

someFunction(1,10)  
// again step isn't defined so expect to log 1 as before
```

> **The problem:**
>
> ```
> someFunction(1,10,2) 
> //step IS defined, shortcut logical OR || should kick in, 
> //step should return 2 BUT it returns 1
> ```

---

I'm aware that this is easily fixed by using braces:

```js
function range(start,end,step){
  var start = start || 1,
      end = end || 100,
      step = step || ((start < end) ? 1:-1);
  console.log(step); 
}
```

---

> **The question:**
>   Why doesn't the `||` operator get short-cut in this case?
>
> I'm aware that the Logical OR has the lowest precedence among binary
>   logical conditional operators but thought that it ***has higher
>   precedence*** than the conditional Ternary operator?
>
> Am I misreading the [MDN docs for Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)?

Comment: "higher precedence" means that your code is being evaluated as `(step || (start < end)) ? 1 : -1`

Comment: “Higher precedence” means `||` is evaluated first, i.e. `step || (start < end)` is evaluated first.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: that would mean that the ternary has greater precedence, right?  MDN docs say otherwise...

Comment: @Xufox: if that was the case then the 3rd call would return 2.  It doesn't...

Comment: @Pineda No… `step || (start < end) ? 1 : -1` evaluates to `step ? 1 : -1` because `||` is evaluated first and `step` is truthy. Then, `step ? 1 : -1` is evaluated to `1` because `step` is truthy.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify what I'm asking...

Comment: You're not reading our comments though.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I realised, I hadn't ask the main question: **why the `||` operator doesn't shortcut**, see @lonesomeday answer.  I've edited it now to clarify.

Comment: It doesn't shortcut because it ends up being the input to the ternary, but it looks like you figured that out in the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the `||` operator has higher precedence than the conditional `?:` operator. This means that it is executed first. From the page you [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

> Operator precedence determines the order in which operators are evaluated. Operators with higher precedence are evaluated first.

Let's have a look at all the operations here:

```
step = step || (start < end) ? 1:-1;
```

The operator with the highest precedence is the `()` grouping operation. Here it results in `false`:

```
step = step || false ? 1 : -1;
```

The next highest precedence is the logical OR operator. `step` is truthy, so it results in `step`.

```
step = step ? 1 : -1;
```

Now we do the ternary operation, which is the only one left. Again, `step` is truthy, so the first of the options is executed.

```
step = 1;
```

Comment: I get this.  What I don't get is why the `||` doesn't shortcut when the left condition is true in this case?

Comment: @Pineda It does. Its left operand is `step` and its right operand is `false`. `false` is never executed.

Comment: `step = step || false ? 1 : -1;` why does `false ? 1:-1` get executed here then, isn't it equivalent to `step = step || (false ? 1 : -1);`

Comment: ah wait... I think I'm getting it, my assumption was that: `false ? 1 : -1` counted as the 2nd condition of the `||`, rather than _just_ false

Comment: @Pineda Yes, the right-hand side *up to the next operator* is the operand, not everything to the right. Think of how `5 + 2 * 3 + 4` is executed. `*` has higher priority than `+` so `2*3` is executed first.

Comment: Thanks. I get that. I've amending my question to remove the brackets.  With the brackets removed from the ternary operator the flow of precedence changes but I still get the error

Comment: Oh wait.  I see, _up to the next operator_.  Fair enough and many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is loosely typed which means that whenever an operator or statement is expecting a particular data-type, JavaScript will automatically convert the data to that type.

Let's see some scenarios how it converts to other type

**example 1.**

if() statement expects a boolean value, 
therefore whatever you define in the brackets will be converted to a boolean.

JavaScript values are often referred to as being "truthy" or "falsey", according to what the result of such a conversion would be (i.e. true or false).

Remember if a value is truthy unless it’s known to be falsey.

Fortunately there are only six falsey -

1. false (of course!)
2. undefined
3. null
4. 0 (numeric zero)
5. "" (empty string)
6. NaN (Not A Number)

**example 2.**

var x = zoo || star ;

If zoo evaluates to true then the value of zoo is returned, otherwise the value of star is returned

**example 3.**

```
var str = '1' || '2';
```

'1' is not falsey so '1' will be returned 
       result : str = '1';

**example 4.**

```
var str = '1' || (true) ? '2' : '3';
```

first of all precedence of ||(Logical OR) operator is greater than ?(Conditional) 
  operator

so first ( '1' || (true) ) will be evaluated first

'1' is not falsey so '1' will be returned

Intermediate result : str = '1' ?' 2' : '3'

'1' is not truthy so '2' will be returned

Final result : str = '2'

**example 5.**

```
var str = '1' || (false) ? '2' : '3';
```

first of all precedence of ||(Logical OR) operator is greater than ?(Conditional) 
  operator

so first ( '1' || (false) ) will be evaluated first

'1' is not falsey so '1' will be returned

Intermediate result : str = '1' ?' 2' : '3'

'1' is not truthy so '2' will be returned

Final result : str = '2'

Now it will be very easy to figure out in your scenario :)