# OR in ternary operator, using &&

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

Using the traditional if statement I can do this:

```
if(a===0 || b===0) {console.log('aloha amigo')};
```

But when I try to do something the same thing with a ternary operator, like this:

```
a===0 || b===0 && console.log('aloha amigo')
```

I just get errors about unexpected ||.

According to this answer: [Precedence: Logical or vs. Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026158/precedence-logical-or-vs-ternary-operator#42026340), we can do it using

```
condition1 || condition2 ? do if true : do if false
```

(Sorry I'm not sure how to call the `? :` symbols in this case), but I'm not sure how to get it running using `&&` (It means only run the code if returned `true`).

I created a codepen to test it easily. Here's the whole code:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;

a===0 || b===0 ? console.log('Works here') : console.log('And here');

a===0 || b===0 && console.log('Doesn\'t work here');

a===0 && console.log('The && works for a single test');
```

[Here's the link](https://codepen.io/Alex-Iron/pen/dKBJXz?editors=1111)

Comment: *"But when I try to do something the same thing with a ternary operator..."* That's not a ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands). That's two binary operators (`||` and `&&` -- operators accepting *two* operands). JavaScript currently has only one ternary operator: The *conditional operator*: `condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse`. It could have another ternary added at some stage, but for now it has only one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just take parenthesis to prevent operator precedence of `&&` over `||`

```
(a === 0 || b === 0) && console.log('aloha amigo')
```

Without parenthesis, you get (now with to show the precedence) a different result.

```
a === 0 || (b === 0 && console.log('aloha amigo'))
^^^^^^^                                             first evaluation
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  second evaluation
```

Comment: Ok this works. But why do I need to get it into parenthesis? I'll select as best in 10 min

Comment: @alex.iron - The bigger question is why are you wasting your time making your code less readable, harder to maintain, and more prone to error? **;-)** Just use the `if`. That's what it's for. Even the author of the language, Brendan Eich, calls the `condition && doSomething();` an *abusage* of the `&&` operator.

Comment: Well I saw it being used by people, it made sense so I started using it. It looks readable though. It's an shorter if statement isn't it?

Comment: @alex.iron - Readability is in the eye of the reader of course. :-) Shorter != better. Leave minification to the minifiers. Instead, write clear, easily modified code. Here, an `if` with a proper block is a couple of characters longer, but much easier to modify down-the-line. Anyway, happy coding!

Comment: @alex.iron - :-) I hope my hyperbole above came across in the friendly spirit it was intended to. Written communication is so hard. Happy coding!